# How do I implement UITextFieldDelegate

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm still learning swift and I was curious on how I implement UITextFieldDelagate. I was also curious on how I should hide the Keyboard(FirstResponder) when it sees that I've finished editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ViewController should be an `UITextFieldDelegate`. You then set the current ViewController as the delegate of the textField, in this case in `viewDidLoad()`.

Implement `textFieldShouldReturn` so the textField delegates the return task (textFieldShouldReturn) to the ViewController. In this method call `resignFirstResponder`, this way the keyboard will disappear. Example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var someTextField: UITextField!

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        someTextField.delegate = self

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Hapeki